# WebGL change uv buffer using the same shader attribute

Tags: attributes, buffer, shader, webgl

I'm trying to render two textures with different UV maps on a 3D plane. But when the application draws the textures it uses only the last uv buffer (with its associated uv coordinates). I have been looking in almost all cases in this forum but none gives me the solution.

This is my app (is the smallest version I could program):

```
const PICTURES = {
    indices: [
        0, 1, 2, 
        0, 3, 1, 
    ],
    vertices: [
        1.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 
        -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 
        -1.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 
        1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 
    ],
    uv_layers: {
        'uv_1': [
            1.000000, 1.077309, 
            0.000000, -0.077309, 
            0.000000, 1.077309, 
            1.000000, -0.077309, 
        ],
        'uv_2': [
            1.500000, 1.500000, 
            -0.500000, -0.500000, 
            -0.500000, 1.500000, 
            1.500000, -0.500000, 
        ],
    },
};

const   vertexShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    attribute vec4  vertex;
    attribute vec2  uv;
    varying vec2        UV;

    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix;

    void main()
    {
        UV = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vertex;
    }`;

const fragmentShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 UV;

    uniform sampler2D bitmap_1;
    uniform sampler2D bitmap_2;

    void main() {
        // Mix the bitmaps in equal proportions
        vec4 px1 = texture2D(bitmap_1, UV) * 0.5;
        vec4 px2 = texture2D(bitmap_2, UV) * 0.5;
        gl_FragColor = px1 + px2;
    }`;

function loadShader(gl, vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode) {
    
    const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
        return null;
    }

    const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
        return null;
    }
    return [vertexShader, fragmentShader];
}

function loadTexture(gl, url) {

    function isPowerOf2(value){ return (value & (value - 1)) == 0; }

    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Because images have to be download over the internet they might take a moment until they are ready.
    // Until then put a single pixel in the texture so we can use it immediately.
    // When the image has finished downloading we'll update the texture with the contents of the image.
    const level                 = 0;
    const internalFormat= gl.RGBA;
    const width                 = 1;
    const height                = 1;
    const border                = 0;
    const srcFormat         = gl.RGBA;
    const srcType               = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    const pixel                 = new Uint8Array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]);  // magenta to warn if there is no texture
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType, pixel);

    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, srcFormat, srcType, image);

        // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
        // power of 2 in both dimensions.
        if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
            // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        } else {
            // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn of mips and set wrapping to clamp to edge
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        }
    };
    image.src = url;

    return texture;
}

function Material(gl, shaders) {

    this.shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(this.shaderProgram, shaders[0]); // Vertex shader
    gl.attachShader(this.shaderProgram, shaders[1]); // Fragment shader
    gl.linkProgram(this.shaderProgram);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(this.shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.shaderProgram));
        return null;
    }
}

function main() {

    var surface = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
    var gl = surface.getContext('webgl');

    if (!gl) {
        alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
        return;
    }


    // -------------------------------------mesh-----------------------------------------

    // Create the index buffer
    const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(PICTURES.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // The vertex buffer
    const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // uv layers buffers (two uv channels for two different bitmaps)
    const uvBuffer_1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_1);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_1']), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    const uvBuffer_2 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_2);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_2']), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // Create the textures for the respectives uv buffers
    const texture_1 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'old_fashioned_portrait.jpg');
    const texture_2 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'demon.jpg');

    // One material for two textures maped within its own uv maps, like any 3D software could allow
    let shaders = loadShader(gl,vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode);
    const material = new Material(gl, shaders);

    let modelMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

    let meshData = {
        indices         : PICTURES.indices,
        indexBuffer : indexBuffer,
        vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer,
        uvBuffer_1  : uvBuffer_1,
        uvBuffer_2  : uvBuffer_2,
        material        : material,
        texture_1       : texture_1,
        texture_2       : texture_2,
        modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
    };

    // Render data and methods
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {render(gl, meshData, Date.now()*0.001);});
}

var rotation = 0.0;

function render(gl, meshData, before)
{
    var now = Date.now()*0.001;
    var delta = now-before;
    rotation += delta;

    // ------------------------------------canvas----------------------------------------

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const aspect            = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const fieldOfView   = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
    const zNear             = 0.1;
    const zFar              = 100.0;

    let projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    let viewMatrix  = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(viewMatrix, viewMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]);
    mat4.rotate(viewMatrix, viewMatrix, rotation*2, [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(viewMatrix, viewMatrix, rotation, [0, 1, 0]);


    // -------------------------------------mesh-----------------------------------------

    gl.useProgram(meshData.material.shaderProgram);

    // Vertices transformations
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'projectionMatrix'), false, projectionMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'viewMatrix'), false, viewMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'modelMatrix'), false, meshData.modelMatrix);

    // Give the GPU the order of the points to form the triangles
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.indexBuffer);

    // Give the GPU the transformed vertices
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'), 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'));

    // First texture mapped in the triangles with the first uv coordinates
    // 'uvBuffer_1' is smashed by 'uvBuffer_2'
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.uvBuffer_1);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'));

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData.texture_1);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_1'), 0);

    // Second texture mapped in the triangles with the second uv coordinates
    // The last uv buffer (mesh.uvBuffer_2) prevails:
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.uvBuffer_2);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'));

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData.texture_2);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_2'), 1);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, meshData.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.useProgram(null);

    requestAnimationFrame(function(){render(gl, meshData, now);});
}

main();
```

The html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>webgl</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../webgl.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        <script src="gl-matrix.js"></script>
        <script>const TEXTURES_FOLDER = 'textures/';</script>
        <script src="webgl.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shaders only use one set of UV coordinates

```
const   vertexShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    attribute vec4  vertex;
    attribute vec2  uv;
    varying vec2        UV;

    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix;

    void main()
    {
        UV = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vertex;
    }`;

const fragmentShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 UV;

    uniform sampler2D bitmap_1;
    uniform sampler2D bitmap_2;

    void main() {
        // Mix the bitmaps in equal proportions
        vec4 px1 = texture2D(bitmap_1, UV) * 0.5;
        vec4 px2 = texture2D(bitmap_2, UV) * 0.5;
        gl_FragColor = px1 + px2;
    }`;
```

If you want to use 2 sets of UV coordinates you need shaders that use 2 sets of UV coordinates

```
const   vertexShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    attribute vec4  vertex;
    attribute vec2  uv1;
    attribute vec2  uv2;
    varying vec2        UV1;
    varying vec2        UV2;

    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix;

    void main()
    {
        UV1 = uv1;
        UV2 = uv2;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vertex;
    }`;

const fragmentShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 UV1;
    varying vec2 UV2;

    uniform sampler2D bitmap_1;
    uniform sampler2D bitmap_2;

    void main() {
        // Mix the bitmaps in equal proportions
        vec4 px1 = texture2D(bitmap_1, UV1) * 0.5;
        vec4 px2 = texture2D(bitmap_2, UV2) * 0.5;
        gl_FragColor = px1 + px2;
    }`;
```

And then of course look up the new attribute locations

```
   // First texture mapped in the triangles with the first uv coordinates
    // 'uvBuffer_1' is smashed by 'uvBuffer_2'
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.uvBuffer_1);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv1'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv1'));

    ...

    // Second texture mapped in the triangles with the second uv coordinates
    // The last uv buffer (mesh.uvBuffer_2) prevails:
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.uvBuffer_2);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I already knew that a posible solution was add more 'attribute var2 uv_N' to the shader. Thanks to your answer, I am convinced that it is not possible to associate more than one buffer to an attribute